Oracle SQLLDR control file: How to accept multiline fields
I have this control file:
Load data into table ODIN_ALERTS_TEST
APPEND
fields terminated by "~"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    REGION,
    POD,
    SEVERITY,
    TARGET_NAME,
    TARGET_TYPE,
    ALERT_MESSAGE,
    ALERT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"',
    ODIN_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"',
    ALERT_URL,
    ODIN_ID,
    COMMENTS,
    OWNER,
    UPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"',
    CLEAR_TIMESTAMP  TIMESTAMP(6) 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"',
    OUTAGE_DURATION_IN_MINUTES,
    EVENT_NAME,
    PUBLISHED_ON,
    ATR_EXEC_ID,
    ATR_STATUS
)


And the comments field can sometimes contain new line, tabs and carriage returns (\r\n\t) and those new lines cause it to just choke. Example:
HCRI~eu-frankfurt-1~Critical~em2bg1w10~Database Instance~Database wait event resmgr:become active count on em2bg1w instance em2bg1w10 is 120.~2024-10-17T00:26:46Z~2024-10-17T00:27:04Z~~2024091419121334497202~ou have selected POD DB Level Health Check ==> Active Session Utilization:                                                                                                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 Checking for Active Session Usage Details on hcri database em2bg1w...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 Active Session Usage Details found in hcri database em2bg1w                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   INST_ID BEGIN_TIME END_TIME   INTSIZE_CSEC   GROUP_ID  METRIC_ID METRIC_NAME                    VALUE METRIC_UNIT                   CON_ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ------------------------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         9 05-OCT-24  05-OCT-24          5945          2       2147 Average Active Sessions   3.07027151 Active Sessions                    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        10 05-OCT-24  05-OCT-24          6048          2       2147 Average Active Sessions   3.60104322 Active Sessions                    0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   INST_ID CPU_COUNT  AAS_CPU_PCT AAS_IO_PCT AAS_ON_ENQ_OW_PCT AAS_ALL_OTHER_PCT AAS_Total on DB Instance                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------------- ----------------- ------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        10 40                4.66        .18                 0             25.41                    30.24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
         9 40                 4.3        .23                 0              1.48                     6.02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
AAS_Total on Database                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
---------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                18.54~JAVVAJI.RAVI~2024-10-05T00:38:57Z~2024-10-17T01:11:46Z~45~fusion:database_wait_event_count_alert~FAAAS:DATABASE~~  

Everything is nicely ~ delimited, until it's not!!!
How can I update this control file to handle this case?

Does the 2nd code block represent data you're loading (the one that begins with HCRI~eu...)? Lines - whose fields are separated by the ~ character are the very first one and the very last one. What about bunch of data in between? Anyway: in my opinion, SQL Loader is a great tool to load structured data. For something like this, I'd probably go with UTL_FILE and parse the input file line-by-line, deciding what to load and what to discard.

The tools at your disposal to control the import of large "comments" in SQLLDR are mainly CONTINUEIF and the "replace()" function.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html

In my practice, I've used 2 workarounds:

Put the text in double quotes and use the streaming option infile '<some path>.<some extension>' "str x'0D'"
Replace the new new lines with some character and then replace back once loaded.


Right now that's what I am being forced to do. It's my back up, but I don't like ever modifying original data.

Which is not very surprising, considering sqlldr is pretty much a tool for loading structured data from formatted files. Generally, if you're not using data pump, it's normal to have such limitations and the need of adjusting data during export in order to make it easier for loading.

You can use SQL LOADER delimiter ENCLOSED BY for comments field.
For example : comments  enclosed by '"'
This tells SQL*Loader to treat everything between double quotes as part of the COMMENTS field, even if it contains newlines or other delimiters.
reference : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html
